# Setting the filepath drupal imce

Tags: image, drupal, path

I want USER1 to have access to sites/all/mytemplate/files, but the default config starts at sites/default/files/.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change that in admin/settings/file-system/settings by replacing the path of your files.